# Texture Linked to Mesh movement

Tags: python, animation, texturing, scripting, animation-nodes

Im trying to find a way to either change a texture or mesh based on the movement of its parent. An example of what I mean would be a Character in those old Top down RPG games where if ZCharacter moved Right you would see ZCharcaters Left side and If they moved Up you would see its back and Down, its front, etc etc.
As i say, could be a pool of textures assigned to a parent that is tied to a direction and applies it live. Or a pool of Geom textured doing the same. But cant for the life of me find a way to do it.

Comment: blender is not a game engine. your question appears to me to be related to a specific game engine

Comment: this would for sure be possible with geometry node + animation nodes